# Delphi - Android development on XIAOMI Pocophone F1

Tags: android, delphi, xiaomi

Got myself a Xiaomi Pocophone F1.
However, I cannot compile android application on the phone, because it won't let me.

It seems I must specify explicitly the source of the installation media and Delphi is not on the list :)

So, does anybody know perhaps what I must do to get the compiler working ?

USB debugging is on and developer options are visible.

Comment: Have you tried revoking computer privileges and reconnecting?

Comment: What do you mean "it won't let me"? You don't compile apps ON the phone. You compile them on a PC first and then DEPLOY them to the phone. Your phone setup has nothing to do with compiling, only with deployment.

Comment: Remy - when you compile in the IDE for android the compilation result is displayed on the connected android phone itself.

Comment: @user763539 the IDE compiles the app binaries locally on the PC first.  Then it uses the [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) to connect to the chosen phone/emulator, deploy the app's files to it, install the app if needed, and execute the app. Enabling USB debugging and Developer options on the phone/emulator is all that is needed for that to work.

Comment: @user763539 If that is not working, you need to clarify what "it won't let me" means. What is "it" exactly? What errors are you getting, if any? On the PC side or the phone side? Are you able to communicate with the phone manually using the Android SDK's `adb.exe` command line tool? If that does not work, the IDE's deployment  will not work, either.

Comment: Have you checked [Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for suggestions.

The issue on that particular phone is that you have to (in developer options under debugging) enable "Install via USB" and "USB debugging - security settings").

It is not as simple as it sounds because you have to create an account on their site (https://account.xiaomi.com/) first. Creating the account for this particular options implies that you can not change the phone's region any more. Why they chose to do this,I do not know.